# Using IntelliJ instead of eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, intellij-idea

I started some spring boot tutorials and used spring tool suit to write some API for a small project that I need . But since I am an android developer I am not familiar with eclipse platform . Can I use spring tool suit in Intelli J (or something like that if the question doesn't stand).

Comment: I am actually doing the same thing, for IntelliJ the community edition cant configure spring & tomcat apps.. But if you are a student then you can get the Intellij Unlimited version for free for 1 year. Based on my experience setting up tomcat & spring in intelliJ is a pain but once its set up intelliJ definitely trumps eclipse. Hope this helps.. 

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Tool Suite (STS) is an IDE built on top of eclipse. It's basically eclipse with a reskin and some plugins built-in.

In other words, no, you can't use STS 'in' intellij. You don't *need* STS to write spring-based java code, but the tutorial you are following probably assumes STS usage.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate comes with native support for Spring Boot. IntelliJ IDEA Community doesn't have it, so you have to depend on the usual Java features when using it.

You should take a look at [CHOOSE YOUR EDITION](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) matrix to see which features are available in which version.